# How can I keep the text highlighted with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, highlight

I'm working on a conceptual project. Text reaveal on selection with highlight.

I have to keep the text highlighted once it is selected.

```
<div class="reveal" id="textToSelect"> 
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">Ctexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
</div>
```

I used execommand to create some spans with background-color on selection.  It's work but execommand is now obsolete.

```
document.getElementById('textToSelect').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
}

document.designMode = "on";
if (range) {
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "red");

document.designMode = "off";
});
```

How can I create those spans without execCommand ? I see answer but maybe too general for this speficic case.

Many thanks in advance for your support !

Comment: Selected means, 'click', or 'mouseup' ?

Comment: on mouseup ideally, I would like to create tags each sides of the range with a background-color to simulate the highlight.

Comment: What is the range? I didn't understood the question in that sentence. When you hover over the `#textToSelect`, you need to highlight the content text ? Is that it ?>

Answer (score 0):

Is the following your expected behaviour on mouse over the `#textToSelect`?

```css
#textToSelect .reveal-text {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#textToSelect:hover .reveal-text {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="reveal" id="textToSelect"> 
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">Ctexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
    <span class="reveal-text">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really. i want to create other spans inside .reveal-text depending to the selection.

For exemple if I have this :
 <span class="reveal-text">Bonjour Monsieur comment allez-vous ? </span>
And then I Highligh  "Monsieur comment". So the DOM will become like this : 

 <span class="reveal-text">Bonjour <span style="background-color: yellow">Monsieur comment</span> allez-vous ? </span>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the color once clicked, you need to add this to your reveal-text class, so in your css file add this:

```
a:active {
  color: red;
}
```

change the color accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have a class for the specific change you want and toggle it with the classList property in JavaScript.

Example:

```
var x = document.querySelector('.text-color');

x.onclick = function() {
  console.log('active');
}
```